# Can we access private document from google drive in iOS?

Tags: iphone, google-drive-api

I am working on google drive api for fetching user's images/photos. But i am getting only public photos of user not Private. Can you please tell me is it possible to fetch private photos too ?

Comment: show us your attempts. likely you havent read the docs on authenticating

Comment: I am facing the same issue, i added following scopes in my project
[kGTLAuthScopeDrivePhotosReadonly, kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly]

I have add a query to fetch only png/jpg files.

let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
        query.pageSize = 10
        query.q = "mimeType = 'image/png' or mimeType = 'image/jpeg'"
        query.fields = "nextPageToken, files"
        service.executeQuery(
            query,
            delegate: self,
            didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
        )

Comment: i am getting all urls for images, but i can see only public images in collectionView. here is the link for photo.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhqrdvh9brmznly/googledrivephoto.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying the same and came up with the solution.

Please give permissions by adding scopes.
private let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeDrivePhotosReadonly, kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly]

Fetch Files:

let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()

```
    query.pageSize = 10
    query.q = "mimeType = 'image/png' or mimeType = 'image/jpeg' or mimeType = 'image/jpg'"
    query.fields = "nextPageToken, files"
    AppSingletonObj.service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
    )
```

for showing images in collection view, i used “file.thumbnailLink”

for fetching original images,

let fetcherURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/(file.identifier)?alt=media"

let fetcher = AppSingletonObj.service.fetcherService.fetcherWithURLString(fetcherURL)

```
            fetcher.beginFetchWithCompletionHandler({ (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("success")
                }
                else {
                    print("failure")
                }
            })
```